# Expected data split by sample

Tags: pyhf

I want to make a plot that shows the 'best fit' after an maximum likelihood fit.

This snippet found somewhere in the docs

```py
bestfit_pars = pyhf.infer.mle.fit(data, m, init_pars, par_bounds)
bestfit_cts  = m.expected_data(bestfit_pars, include_auxdata = False)
```

gives the overall expected data given the fit result. Is there a way to break this down by sample? Ideally without having to manually try to apply the corresponding parameters to each sample.

Also, if I understand this correctly: in case of multiple channels, `bestfit_cts` contains the concatenation of all bins of all channels. I can do some index wrangling here, but is there a more straight forward way to map channels to a slice of `bestfit_cts`?

Comment: We've got an open PR here for it (https://github.com/scikit-hep/pyhf/pull/731) and this is currently on our next-patch-release roadmap so it's likely we'll get this in sooner rather than later. Once it's in, we can provide an answer on how to use it. As for channels, we can certainly provide a better API for this as well. Model.config.channels gives the ordering, and Model.config.channel_nbins gives nbins per channel for right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With https://github.com/scikit-hep/pyhf/pull/731 merged, this is now possible using a construction like

```py
# set up
bestfit_cts = m.main_model.expected_data(bestfit_pars, return_by_sample=True)
for sample_name, sample_cts in zip(m.config.samples, bestfit_cts):
  pass
```